# Run command in command line option linux

Tags: bash

I need to launch google chrome on linux with the following command line parameter:

```
google-chrome --touch-devices=14
```

in order to identify the touch screen correctly. Of course, the touchscreen device number changes in a new session.

I can find out what number (here 14) I need to input to the command by running the following:

```
xinput -list | grep -o "Touchscreen.*id=[0-9]*" | grep -o  [0-9]*
```

Naturally, it would be nice to be able to embed these into one command, but I have no clue how to run the command inside the command line option.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
google-chrome --touch-devices="$(xinput -list | grep -o "Touchscreen.*id=[0-9]*" | grep -o  [0-9]*)"
google-chrome --touch-devices="`xinput -list | grep -o "Touchscreen.*id=[0-9]*" | grep -o  [0-9]*`"
```

The first is prefered.

<sup>*TIP: The best practice is to run the `xinput` command first, make sure the output is the expected one and then pass it to `google-chrome`*</sup>

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I still have a lot to learn about the basics.

Comment: @alinafdima: it's never too late :)

Comment: Quoting the command substitutions in case something goes wrong and they return more than one word is likely a good idea. Better would be to error check separately of course.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
$ google-chrome --touch-devices="$(xinput -list | grep -o "Touchscreen.*id=[0-9]*" | grep -o  [0-9]*)"
```

Comment: Quoting the command substitutions in case something goes wrong and they return more than one word is likely a good idea. Better would be to error check separately of course.